# Backbonejs - Back button doesn't work if page transition on same page

Tags: backbone.js, routes, event-handling, transition

Short description of my program and finally the problem:

I have got two pages. The first page list products in rows with a short description. If you click on one you will land on a detail page.

The detail page lists the product details and underneath a couple of related products. If you click on one of the releated products the same page is rendered again with the new information fetched from a REST interface.

If I want to use the browser-back-button or the own back-button to get to the previous product-detail-page a blank page appears. This only happens on my iPad. Using Chrome on a desktop browser works fine. I debugged the application and I figured out, that the backbonejs route is never called. I have no idea why.

Here is my code of the details page:

```
define([ 
    "jquery", 
    "lib/backbone",
    "lib/text!/de/productDetails.html"
], 
function( 
    $, 
    Backbone, 
    ContentTemplate
){
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // product details template
        template: _.template(ContentTemplate),

        // back-button clicked
        events:{
            'click a#ac-back-button':'backInHistory',
        },

        // init
        initialize: function(options){

               this.options=options;

               // bind functions
               _.bindAll(this, 
                  'render',
                  'renderRelatedSeriePlainproduct',
                  'backInHistory'
            );

        // listen for collection
        this.listenTo(this.options.relatedCollectionPlainproduct, 'reset',this.renderRelatedSeriePlainproduct);
        },

        // back button
        backInHistory: function(e){

               e.preventDefault();

               window.history.back();
        },

        // render template 
        render: function(){

           // render template
               this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.models[0].attributes));
           return this;
        },

        // render related products
        renderRelatedSeriePlainproduct: function (){

               var models = this.options.relatedCollectionPlainproduct.models;

               if(models.length==0){
                  $('.ac-plainproduct').hide();
               } else{

              var elem = $('#ac-related-listing-plainproduct');

                  var ct="";
                  ct+='<ul id="ac-list-related-plainproduct">';
                  $.each(models, function(key, value){
                     ct+='<li>';
                     ct+='<a href="index.html?article_id='+value.get('article_id')+'&type='+value.get('type')+'&serie='+value.get('series')+'#product-detail">Link';
                    ct+='</a>';
                    ct+='</li>';
                });
                ct+='</ul>';

                elem.append(ct);
            }
        }


    });

    // Returns the View class
    return PageView;
});
```

I follow one of the links from **renderRelatedSeriePlainproduct**.If I click on the back button on the new page the **backInHistory** function is called, but the **window.history.back();** does not call the backbone router.

Maybe the problem is the #hash in the URL, that is not changed during page transition. But this would not explain, why it works perfectly with my Chrome on my desktop machine. For me it seemed to be a problem of asynchronous calls but even there I could not find a problem.

Maybe it helps to list my router code as well. First of all I was thinking it is an zombie issue in backbone, but I remove all events and views while making the transition.

```
// function called by the route
// details page
productdetail: function() {

            $.mobile.loading("show");

            _self = this;

            // lazy loading
            require([
               'collection/ProductDetailCollection',
               'collection/RelatedCollection',
               'view/ProductDetailView'
            ], 
            function(ProductDetailCollection, RelatedCollection, ProductDetailView){

                // get URL parameters
                var articleID   = _self.URLParameter('article_id');
                var type        = _self.URLParameter('type');
                var serie       = _self.URLParameter('serie');

                // product - details
                var productDetail   = new ProductDetailCollection.ProductDetail({id: articleID});

                // related products
                _self.relatedCollectionPlainproduct = new RelatedCollection({serie:serie, type:"Electronics", article_id:articleID});

                // assign binded context 
                productDetail.fetch({

                    // data fetched
                    success: function (data) {

                        // page transition
                        _self.changePage(new ProductDetailView({
                            model:data,  
                            relatedCollectionPlainproduct:_self.relatedCollectionPlainproduct
                        }));

                        // fetch data
                        _self.relatedCollectionPlainproduct.fetch({reset:true});
                    }
                });
            });
},

// page transition
changePage:function (page) {

            // remove previous page from DOM
            this.page && this.page.remove() && this.page.unbind();

            // assign
            this.page = page;

            // assign page tag to DOM
            $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');

            // render template
        page.render();

        // append template to dom
        $('body').append($(page.el));

        // set transition
        var transition = "fade";

        // we want to slide the first page different
        if (this.firstPage) {

                transition = "fade";
            this.firstPage = false;
        }

        // make transition by jquery mobile
        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:true, transition: transition});

        // page was rendered - trigger event
        page.trigger('render');

        $.mobile.loading("hide");
    },
```

I tried to use allowSamePageTransition but with no success. Maybe someone could give me a hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery Mobile and Backbone's routers are conflicting. Take a look here:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the reason. I disabled the routing of jquery mobile.

```
// Prevents all anchor click handling
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

// Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```